# When using operators, does using multiple operators effect code speed?

Tags: javascript, java, php, plsql, binary-operators

Just had this discussion in class and no one seems to think it makes a difference, but my question is if I use 1 binary operator to do a check, does it perform faster than 2? Hard to explain but here's an example:

```
// 1 Operator
if (i < 10) { // Does 1 check and then proceeds
  ...         // Is i < 10? Ok. Proceed.
}

// 2 Operators
if (i <= 9) { // Does 2 checks before proceeding
   ...        // Is i < 9? No? Ok, does i = 9? Ok. Proceed.
}
```

My logic tells me that yes it does take longer. With our powerful systems I'm sure it makes a non-measurable difference but in theory if we stacked a billion of these statements together, would the one doing 1 check run faster than the other?

Comment: In many languages (perhaps most, if not all?), both < and <= are defined as operators, i.e. <= is 1 operator, not 2. But I'll leave it to someone way more intelligent than me to tell you how this maps onto processor operations, and hence impact on speed.

Comment: No, it does not take longer.  Most if not all modern CPUs have single instructions for both less-than and less-than-or-equal.  So either way, it's one instruction.  I realize it's easy to fall under the impression that tokens in code which use more characters must be somehow slower, but that hasn't been the case for decades.